# How do I create an Exchange/Outlook rule to copy user's Sent Items to their Personal Folders counterpart?

Tags: windows, exchange, outlook, messaging

I have yet to meet an user dedicated enough to keep his/her mailbox tidy, not to mention moving sent messages to the PST in order to keep the storage quota in shape. The most common reason being that they just don't find an easy way to create a Rule to do that. So basically I was wondering if there's any tip/script you would like to share to help me make their lives a bit easier?

Thanks much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating the rule is easy.  You can create it once, export it and let users Import it into their own set of rules.  (This is what we've done to create a rule that checks SpamAssassin SMTP headers on the way in in order to move flagged messages to the SPAM folder).

1. Turn off the option to save sent items
2. Create a new blank rule, select Check messages after sending)
3. Don't select anything in the Select Conditions
4. In the Select actions screen choose move a copy to the specified folder and pick the PST's folder
5. Click Finish

The benefit that using a rule like this has over AutoArchive is that the messages never touch the Sent Items folder in the mailbox and thus never clog up the server stores.

Answer (score 3):

What's wrong with AutoArchive?  That should do exactly what you need.  Here's a link:

[Microsoft KB 830119](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/830119)

Comment: Agreed...this is the whole purpose of AutoArchive.

Comment: @scotthere: First all thanks for the tip! Although I've considered AutoArchive I'm still not totally convinced given that, in practice, many users seems to skip the "run AutoArchive now" dialog more often than not, therefore the need for a perhaps more transparent solution.

Comment: But if you schedule it to run they should not need to take any action. They might see it run in the toolbar and cancel it, but I don't see any reason that would happen.